# Как процессор понимает уровень колец защиты?

Tags: linux, архитектура, ос, процессор, ядро

Кольца защиты реализованы на аппаратном уровне, ядро имеет доступ ко всем ресурсам, то есть ядро ОС использует эту аппаратную возможность для реализации этой защиты? Можно написать ядро ОС так чтобы не было никакой защиты, так?

Comment: Можно. Просто не меняйте уровень при запуске нового процесса

Comment: @avp а как процессор меняет уровень? Это делает ОС?

Comment: @Venot -"как процессор меняет уровень? " Если не вдаваться в двоичные команды, то идея такая: ядро ведёт список процессов, которые исполняются в данный момент. В этом списке отмечается, какие процессы пользовательские, а какие - ядра. Каждый квант времени планировщик пробегает по этому списку и ищет (в соответствии с приоритетами) первый процесс, готовый к исполнению. Формируется команда переключения процесса, в которой указывается адрес продолжения выполения и уровень кольца. Начинает выполнятся очередной процесс в соответствующем кольце.